# JPA merge is inserting instead of updating

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a database with a field `NAME` and I need to upload a picture as blob type to a field `PICTURE` on every entity whose `NAME` is equal to the file name. However, upon running the code creates a bunch of new entities with duplicated `NAME` fields and `PICTURE` fields.
Here is my code:

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File currentDir = new File("C:\\Users\\luccaskammer\\Desktop\\Imagens\\"); // Define o diretorio a ser lido
    displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
}

public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
    try {

        ImagensParaDBController contr = new ImagensParaDBController();
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        DeletePng del = new DeletePng();
        //ConvertData conv = new ConvertData();

        for (File file: files) {

            ImagensParaBD img = new ImagensParaBD();
            ImagensParaBD name = new ImagensParaBD();
            ImagensParaBD picture = new ImagensParaBD();

            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                displayDirectoryContents(file);
            }

            else if (file.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("     file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                img.setName(del.deletePng(file.getName()));
                java.nio.file.Path filelocation = Paths.get(file.getCanonicalPath());
                img.setPicture(Files.readAllBytes(filelocation));
                contr.insertImageDB(img, picture, name);
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("invalid");
            }
        }

        contr.disconnect();

    }
    catch(IOException e) {}
}
```

**Bean**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "planegeo")

public class ImagensParaBD implements Serializable {@Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    //private String pathFolder;
    private String name;@Lob
    private byte[] picture;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public byte[] getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(byte[] picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public class ImagensParaDBController {

    EntityManagerFactory mf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mySQLPU");
    EntityManager em = mf.createEntityManager();

    public void insertImageDB(ImagensParaBD img, ImagensParaBD name, ImagensParaBD picture) {

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(img);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    public void disconnect() {

        em.close();
    }

    public void insertImageDB(ImagensParaBD img) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you create new instances. Instead you have to retrieve from DB all the ImagensParaBD  where name=required.

Your newly created instances have no id so hibernate just inserts them.

```
List<ImagensParaBD> all = em.createQuery("Select a From ImagensParaBD a where name=:name", 
ImagensParaBD.class)
.setParameter("name", theNameTOFind)
.getResultList();
```

and then iterate the instances adding the info and merging them

Comment: Thank you for your input! However, that didnt work for me. I did this update to the code:
`code
  em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query queryName= em.createQuery(from table_name where picture = :picture);
        queryName.setParameter("picture",picture).setParameter("name", name);

        List<ImagensParaBD> result = queryName.getResultList();
        ImagensParaBD imagensParaBD = new ImagensParaBD();
        imagensParaBD = result.get(0);
        em.merge(imagensParaBD);
        em.getTransaction().commit(); `

Answer (score 0):

JPA will try to find database row object from ID. 
if the your Id is same as Database ID the only JPA merge the row.

Here your are passing only picture object.
So first Try to find object from database.
If it exist in database then fetch ID and setID in your object.
I will work.

Sample code:

```
Query queryName= em.createQuery(from table_name where picture = :picture);
queryName.setParameter("picture",your picture Object);

list<ImagensParaBD> result = queryName.getResultList();
ImagensParaBD imagensParaBD = new ImagensParaBD();
imagensParaBD = result.get(0);
em.merge(imagensParaBD);
```